# ESPAsyncWebServer switch page after upload file to ESP8266

Tags: html, upload, switch-statement, webserver, esp8266

In my ESP8266 I am using the ESPAsyncWebServer lib.

My purpose is to upload a file to ESP8266 and after uploading the website should be switched to another one.

The html code is:

```
const char upload_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>File Upload</title></head>
<body><h1>File Upload</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/uploadDo" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
<input type="file" name="upload"><input type="submit" value="Upload"></form>
<form action="/"><button onclick="window.location.href='/'">Back</button></form>
<iframe style="visibility: hidden;" src="http://" )+local_IPstr+"/Usm" name="iframe"></iframe>
</body></html>
)rawliteral";
```

the server upload:

```
mServer.on("/uploadDo", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    CONSOLELN(F("uploadDo"));
    request->send(200); }, handleUpload);       
  mServer.on("/upload", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    CONSOLELN(F("upload"));  
    request->send(200, "text/html", upload_html);
```

and the handleUpload process:

```
void handleUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest *request, String filename, size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final) {
  String logmessage = "Client:" + request->client()->remoteIP().toString() + " " + request->url();
  CONSOLELN(logmessage);

  if (!index) {
    SPIFFS.begin();
    logmessage = "Upload Start: " + String(filename);
    request->_tempFile = SPIFFS.open("/" + filename, "w");
    CONSOLELN(logmessage);
  }
  if (len) {
    request->_tempFile.write(data, len);
    logmessage = "Writing file: " + String(filename) + " index=" + String(index) + " len=" + String(len);
    CONSOLELN(logmessage);
  }
  if (final) {
    logmessage = "Upload Complete: " + String(filename) + ",size: " + String(index + len);
    request->_tempFile.close();
    CONSOLELN(logmessage);
    FSzeigen();
    readFile(SPIFFS,filename.c_str());
    //request->redirect("/");
    //request->send(200, "/start.html");
    /*
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(200, "text/plain", "Ok");
    response->addHeader("Test-Header", "My header value");
    request->send(response);
    */
    //request->send(303,"/start.html");
    request->send(200, "text/html", "<a href=\"/\">Return to Home Page</a>");
  }
}
```

When I get the final signal I want to change to another website that I send in the last line  request->send(200, "text/html", "<a href="/">Return to Home Page");
But this doesn't seem to work and it stays on the upload_html site.

complete code is here: [text](https://github.com/sky4walk/BrausteuerungV4/blob/master/Software/src/Steuerung_1.0/SteuerungWebServer.cpp)

I need also to mention that I am not so familiar with html handling and there are many examples out there but I think I am too stupid to transfer it to my solution :-)

Thank you

Find a solution for switching to another html site when the upload is finished so the user could see that the upload is finished.